# How to spawn async function that mutate states in a single-threaded program?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a single-threaded async program built on tokio, and its states (a, b) are only updated synchronously. In theory, it doesn't need a lock while mutating the state. The following code shows the idea but it fails to compile.

```
struct Program {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
}

impl Program {
    pub async fn run(mut self) {
        let local = tokio::task::LocalSet::new();
        local.spawn_local(async move {
            self.modify_x().await;
        });
        local.spawn_local(async move {
            self.modify_x().await;
        });
        local.await;
    }

    pub async fn modify_a(&mut self) {
        self.a = async_fn1().await;
    }

    pub async fn modify_b(&mut self) {
        self.b = async_fn2().await;
    }
}
```

There are a few ways I tried that can solve this issue:

1. simply move the entire function body into the async closure
2. move the state to a `thread_local` variable and wrap it with `RefCell`, spawn a static member function like `Self::modify_x()`

I tried but failed

1. move the state be a field of Program and wrap it with RefCell. But it requires `self` to outlive `'static`, even though I called `local.await` before the end of the function [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92f201c18475dacd825a22061c42395e)

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and convenient way to express this single-threaded behavior (without requiring Mutex or Arc), e.g. can I wrap `self` with RefCell?

Comment: If `modify_a` and `modify_b` are as presented and only do synchronous work, then making them async doesn't help anything especially in a single-threaded environment. They won't run concurrently at all.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear. it's just a minimal example, `modify_a` and `modify_b` will do async work, but `&mut self` is never moved into an async closure.